# How do I change screens kivymd map app with button?

Tags: python, kivy, maps, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to click a button which directs me to the map. Then when I click a button on the window of the map I want to go back to the beginning window https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxAr2.png

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add name to every screen and add ScreenManager
then change screens by using `on_release`
in .kv:

```
ScreenManager:
    SomeScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<SomeScreen>
    name: "somename"

    Button:
        on_release: ScreenManager.current = "secondname"

<SecondScreen>
    name: "secondname"
```

in .py
you need to add these things

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class SomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass
```